# Find and remove date in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, rss

I use RSS to get posts from my WordPress website and in its name have date in title and I want to remove the date from its title and use date from rss instead

[The Result I want (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq7fU.png) I want to remove date on title (red cross) and use rss date(green underline) instead

The problem is date format in title is not international format

Any idea to make jQuery to detect this date formula and replace(remove) it?

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-langs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sd.ac.th/main/wp-content/rss_fetch/FeedEk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#divRss').FeedEk({
            FeedUrl: 'http://www.sd.ac.th/main/?feed=rss2&cat=121',
            //FeedUrl: 'http://www.sd.ac.th/main/?feed=rss2&cat=234',
            MaxCount: 10,
            ShowPubDate: true,
            ShowDesc: false
        });

        /*setInterval(function(){
            $('.itemTitle a').each(function() {
                   var text = $(this).text();
                    $(this).text(text
                        .replace('[', '')
                        .replace(']', '')
                        .replace('59', '')
                        .replace('60', '')
                    );
            });}
        , 1);*/
    });
    function reloadFunction() {
    location.reload();
    }
</script>
<button onclick="reloadFunction()">R</button>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.sd.ac.th/main/wp-content/rss_fetch/rss_style.css">
<div id="divRss"></div>
```

**FeedEk.js** (Plugin that I use for fetching my feed)

```
/*
* FeedEk jQuery RSS/ATOM Feed Plugin v3.0 with YQL API
* http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html  https://github.com/enginkizil/FeedEk
* Author : Engin KIZIL http://www.enginkizil.com   
*/

(function ($) {
    $.fn.FeedEk = function (opt) {
        var def = $.extend({
            MaxCount: 5,
            ShowDesc: true,
            ShowPubDate: true,
            DescCharacterLimit: 0,
            TitleLinkTarget: "_blank",
            DateFormat: "",
            DateFormatLang:"en"
        }, opt);

        var id = $(this).attr("id"), i, s = "", dt;
        $("#" + id).empty();
        if (def.FeedUrl == undefined) return;       
        $("#" + id).append('<img src="loader.gif" />');

        var YQLstr = 'SELECT channel.item FROM feednormalizer WHERE output="rss_2.0" AND url ="' + def.FeedUrl + '" LIMIT ' + def.MaxCount;

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + encodeURIComponent(YQLstr) + "&format=json&diagnostics=false&callback=?",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#" + id).empty();
                if (!(data.query.results.rss instanceof Array)) {
                    data.query.results.rss = [data.query.results.rss];
                }
                $.each(data.query.results.rss, function (e, itm) {
                    s += '<li><div class="itemTitle"><a href="' + itm.channel.item.link + '" target="' + def.TitleLinkTarget + '" >' + itm.channel.item.title + '</a></div>';

                    if (def.ShowPubDate){
                        dt = new Date(itm.channel.item.pubDate);
                        s += '<div class="itemDate">';
                        if ($.trim(def.DateFormat).length > 0) {
                            try {
                                moment.lang(def.DateFormatLang);
                                s += moment(dt).format(def.DateFormat);
                            }
                            catch (e){s += dt.toLocaleDateString();}                            
                        }
                        else {
                            s += dt.toLocaleDateString();
                        }
                        s += '</div>';
                    }
                    if (def.ShowDesc) {
                        s += '<div class="itemContent">';
                         if (def.DescCharacterLimit > 0 && itm.channel.item.description.length > def.DescCharacterLimit) {
                            s += itm.channel.item.description.substring(0, def.DescCharacterLimit) + '...';
                        }
                        else {
                            s += itm.channel.item.description;
                         }
                         s += '</div>';
                    }
                });
                $("#" + id).append('<ul class="feedEkList">' + s + '</ul>');
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always and the only thing between brackets (`[` and `]`) and it's always at the end of the string then use this:

```
text = text.replace(/(\[.*\])$/, replacementDateString);
```

Read about **Regular Expression**.